# optimize equation by put indexes of a set's elements

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, operations-research

suppose S is a set contains n elements and each element showed by S<sub>i</sub>. S<sub>i</sub>'s are positive natural numbers.put indexes(1 to n) to elements of S so that y will be the lowest amount.     y =∑<sub>j=1</sub><sup>n</sup>(∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>j</sup> s<sub>i</sub>/ s<sub>j</sub>) and s<sub>0</sub> = 0. for example if S={1,2,3} y will be y= 1/1 + (2+1)/2+(2+1+3)/3 = 4.5 or y= 1/1 + (1+3)/3+ (1+3+2)/2 = 16/3 and for now the minimum amount of y is 4.5 and until now indexes must select like s<sub>1</sub> = 1 and  s<sub>2</sub> = 2 and s<sub>3</sub> = 3 which y could be minimum so that way to find indexes of S which y will be the lowest amount

Comment: Welcome to SE. It's unclear what you are asking. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question for information on how to attract quality answers. Proper formatting is expected.

Comment: thanx @mlc i edited my question and i try write it as clear as i could